# Volume keys keep adjusting speakers instead of plugged-in headphones

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer, headphone-jack, media-keys

In Windows 7 when I have headphones plugged in they disconnect the laptop speakers and become the default playback device. However, when I subsequently use the keyboard's volume keys, Windows ignores this and keep adjusting the "Speakers" device that's no longer the default playback device.

I don't understand this behavior — I would've thought that if anything it's the default device that gets adjusted if there's any ambiguity.

How do I force Windows to do the sensible thing? Adjusting the speakers is absolutely useless to me when audio is exclusively playing through headphones.

I can even disable the speakers device entirely *and Windows still won't adjust the headphones' volume levels* with the volume keys.